# Codeigniter verify street address

Tags: codeigniter, verification

I am creating a webpage and would like to have it so that when a street address is entered the program verifies that the street address exists. I was wondering if anyone could recommend a way that this would be possible? Maybe an API or an example someone has done before? I'm just not sure how to go about doing this task and would like to get opinions on a starting point if its possible.

Comment: The street address or email address?

Comment: Sorry, street address.

Comment: try this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34339521/google-maps-api-how-to-check-if-an-address-or-location-is-valid)

Comment: Maybe SmartyStreets could work for you.

Comment: Hmm, I'll take a look at both. I did see SmartyStreets in my search.